# Automatically clicking divs present on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to automatically click present buttons which are visible on a page, than triggering the scroll functionality after we've clicked the visible options.

I've messed around with the following code, however it didn't work in any formation I applied it.

```
$( ".follow-button" ).trigger( "click" );
```

And here's the button HTML.

```
<button class="follow-button btn-simple"><span class="following-txt">Following</span><span class="follow-txt">Follow</span></button>
```

Comment: because it's hard to understand your issue may you create a fiddle or describe better your issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the visible buttons, now how you implemented it, checking the class and ignoring with class hidden or whatever is up to you

```js
const buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

Array.from(buttons).forEach(b => {
  b.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(b.textContent);
  })
  b.click();
});
```

```html
<button>asdf</button>
<button>hfdg</button>
<button>sfdf</button>
<button>ggfg</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(".follow-button:visible").click()` to click on all visible buttons.